# Refusal of Tourist Schengen VISA - Twice - Italy Embassy

Tags: visas, schengen, italy, visa-refusals

My Tourist Schengen VISA application was rejected for 1st time on 16-Apr-2015 with reason as “Your intention to leave the territory of the Member States before the expiry of the Visa could not be ascertained”.

Based on rejected reason stated, I had re-applied for Tourist Schengen VISA on 23-Apr-2015.
The covering letter in my application I have clearly mentioned:

1. My purpose of visit (which is Sightseeing and Tourist purpose)
2. My obligations because of which I need to return back to INDIA after my tour,
3. My Itinerary with every single details of my Hotel Booking, Travel Bookings with address and Telephone numbers & confirmations for the same and
4. My willingness to visit Embassy office if they needed to interview me or need to speak to me

However my Tourist Schengen VISA application was again rejected for 2nd time on 24-Apr-2015 with a new reason as “Justification for the purpose and conditions of the intended stay was not provided”.

I am really not clear as to what exact information or Justification are they looking for, which I may have not provided in my previous applications.

My friend with whom I have planned this tourist trip was granted VISA when he submitted same documentations (because we planned to travel in same trains and flights and stay in same hotels during our trip) with similar covering letter. However my application was rejected twice.

Can someone please help me what should I be doing?

1. Reapply again with Italy Embassy
2. Appeal to Tribunale Amministrativo Regionale (T.A.R.) (regional administrative court) of Lazio. Any contacts how I can get this done and what could be the time and fees?
3. Should I apply from any other county? I am visiting France, Switzerland, Germany and Italy
4. My passport is being stamped every time by Embassy with Date and VISA TYPE on it.

Will this be problem in future?

Comment: How long is your trip? And how long did your request in the visa application?

Comment: Gayot... I told them my visit was sightseeing and tourist purpose. For 1st time I used COX and KINGS for getting my VISA done.. For 2nd time I personally submitted the application at VFS office. 

Ayesh... My Traveling dates are June 5th to 13th June this year... I did not mention how long I need visa for.. But asked to provide me visa for my trip. I have enclosed every single details of my Iternary with dates, time, address of hotels phone numbers, how I made those bookings with supporting documentation submitted.

Comment: I was thinking your visa duration (30 days, 3 month, 6 month) was unreasonable compared to the proofs you had. It doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: @AyeshK I did not understand what you are saying. Can you tell me if I was wrong somewhere in my application? because of which they refused my visa?

Comment: It's going to be pretty much the same answer as here. http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/49478/schengen-visa-refused-from-german-embassy  Marking this as a duplicate