# Is it possible to obtain a Schengen visa that is valid for more than 2 years?

Tags: visas, schengen, indian-citizens, long-stay-visas

I am an Indian citizen currently working in UK. I have to travel from time to time in Schenghen countries.

Can get a long-term visa (not less than two years)?

Comment: It is possible: Denmark, for example, apparently issues Schengen visas with up to five-year validity https://www.nyidanmark.dk/en-us/coming_to_dk/visa/duration/multiple-entry_long-term_visas.htm -- but note that you cannot stay in the Schengen area for more than 90 days at a time on any Schengen visa (you need a long-stay visa or residence permit in a Schengen country for that).

Comment: @pnuts, the OP wants a long-term "C" visa.

Comment: Why the down votes? What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

You can get a Schengen short stay visa with a validity of up to 5 years if you qualify.  Holding a work permit in the UK may help qualify you, but will not be enough to carry the application by itself.

Referring to the guidance...

> An applicant having proved his integrity and reliability, in
>   particular the lawful use of previous uniform visas or visas with
>   limited territorial validity, his economic situation in the country of
>   origin and his genuine intention to leave the territory of the Member
>   States before the expiry of the visa applied for and who proves the
>   need or justifies the intention to travel frequently and/or regularly,
>   in particular due to his occupational or family status:
>
> - business persons
> - (list of other people who might qualify)

Source: [Schengen Handbook](http://ec.europa.eu/dgs/home-affairs/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/visa-policy/docs/20140709_visa_code_handbook_consolidated_en.pdf)

I interpret this to mean you need to get lots of performance history with normal 90 day Schengens before they will issue a longer term visa.  In comparison, the UK will normally issue a 2 year visitor visa if the person has about 5 - 10 previous visas over the course of about 5 years.

In addition to performance history, the text indicates that your [premise](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/50764/schengen-visa-refusal-from-the-spanish-consulate/50770#50770) will play a large part in their decision.

Others have pointed out in comments that the standard [90/180 rule](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13183/about-schengen-90-180-rule) still applies.

So for your question:  Yes, you can apply for a long-term visitor Schengen.  If they do not want to issue it but you otherwise qualify, they will fall back to issuing you the normal 90 day visa.

Adding...

They will not issue a visa that extends beyond the expiry of your current passport (or to be exact, the expiry date reduced by three months).