# German (Schengen) internship visa rejected. How to appeal?

Tags: indian-citizens, visa-refusals, schengen-visas

I am an Indian national living in Beijing, China (work permit). I recently applied for internship visa (Schengen visa >90 days) in China and received a refusal letter stating "**Your intention to leave the territory of the Member States before the expiry of the visa applied for could not be ascertained.**"

Application process for the visa itself was complicated as the visa center have not come across an immigrant with work visa applying for Schengen visa.

I have provided the following documents before:

- Invitation letter
- Experience certificate from my ex-employer
- NOC (no objection letter) from my ex-employer
- Fully paid to and fro flight tickets
- Accommodation details for my whole stay
- Medical insurance worth 40000 euros
- Bank statement to prove sufficient funds
- Education certificates

I am preparing my Remonstration letter (appeal letter) now to prove them that I'll be leaving the country within my visa dates and thinking of adding the following documents:

- Reason why I applied for visa in China being an Indian national (India has a 3 month home stay rule before applying for Schengen Visa as I've been working in China for the past 2 years)
- 2 year old police background verification certificate from the government of India
- Scanned pages of the list of visas I've been granted before and exit stamp proof from passport stating I've never over stayed
- Mention in the letter that I am a masters graduate from so&so university and always maintained good character. I'd never risk everything and overstay as I am aware it is punishable by law.

Please suggest me if I am thinking right or I'd require any additional document to prove my point.

Comment: There are answers to other questions on this site that explain the refusal reason. See, e.g., at http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/49478/schengen-visa-refused-from-german-embassy or http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/53411/schengen-visa-refusal-justification-for-the-purpose-and-conditions-of-the-inten - while they only fit 95% to your case, they still contain the best advice that you can get.

Comment: On a related note: Did you have any document for proving that you still have a job in China after returning from the internship? Does this document state how much you earn and prove that it's a well paying job? If you look at the answers to the other questions, you will see that the refusal reason is used whenever the embassy employee is unsure whether you will return after the internship. Give proofs for why you will do that!

Comment: Providing character evidence is extremely unlikely to help an application. What consular officers are supposed to ask is whether the applicant has **something else than a general predisposition to follow the law** that motivates them to return home after the planned stay. They don't care about "good character"; they care about actual circumstances that would make even a crook consider returning to be in his selfish interest.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the German officials are not convinced that you will return to China or to India after your internship.

- A former employer in China is no compelling reason for you to return to China.
- There seems to be no compelling reason for you to return to India, either.

Your appeal should focus on those things. An old background check from India won't help much. A new job contract in China for the time after your internship would be much better.

Also, have you talked to the people where you have your internship? A major company with a good legal department might be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

1.You would also need a ZAV letter commonly known as the work permit from the Arbeits Agentur. Is this "invitation letter" your Internship agreement/contract? And does it have the exact dates of your internship? 
2. Its a little illogical to go for an "internship" in Germany when you are already working in China assuming its a full-time job. Mostly, an internship is for undergraduate/postgraduate students who have a "mandator internship" thing in their curriculum. (Its a rule in Germany)