# Can I still get a tourist visa in the UK even when not employed

Tags: visas, uk

I was invited to visit the United Kingdom by my grandparents who live there.

I am unemployed but I just came back from the USA for a cultural exchange program for 1 year. And this is my second time to go to the USA. My first time was in 2013 and my second time in 2017.

I also have a bank statement that shows at least $5,000. This money is from a cultural exchange program.

Comment: If, while you're in the UK, somebody offered you a job, what would be your reason for rejecting the offer and going back to your home country instead?

Comment: your answer to my question is not connected to your answer.

Comment: x @Bienne: Yes it is: That is the question your application needs to answer. If you don't have a good and documentable answer to it, you won't get a visa.

Comment: Alright thanks then. I hope i can get visa soon but offcourse i need to have a stable job to get a visa

Answer (score 5):

I daresay it’s not impossible to get a U.K. visit visa when unemployed, if you can demonstrate a strong travel history and sufficient close family ties in your home country to convince the ECO that you will leave at the end of your visit. However, without a job to go back to and with family in the U.K., your profile is pretty high risk from an ECOs point of view, as Henning Makholm’s comment above indicates. There is a great schematic here [Schengen visa refused from German embassy](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/49478/schengen-visa-refused-from-german-embassy) which, whilst it references Schengen specifically, shows how the ECOs risk assessment of your application might go. If you do apply, I’d suggest you resist the temptation to ask for a long visit, and have a good, provable, reason for it e.g. grandparents’ 30th wedding anniversary or some such. But overall if I were you I’d wait until I had a job in my home country.

Comment: Thank you for those advice and i will follow those advice have a good one!