# How do I appeal my visa rejection?

Tags: visa-refusals

My visa to Spain was rejected with the reason that my intention to leave the territory of the member state before the expiry of the visa could not be ascertained.

I'm 17 years old and I finished secondary school in 2017. How do I appeal it? Or what should I do?

Answer (score 2):

Possibly. There is an excellent answer here [Schengen Visa Refusal: Justification for the purpose and conditions of the intended stay was not reliable](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/53411/schengen-visa-refusal-justification-for-the-purpose-and-conditions-of-the-inten) which explains how lack of ties (eg a job) can harm an application and the steps you can consider taking. Also this one explaining how the risk assessment process works. [Schengen visa refused from German embassy](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/49478/schengen-visa-refused-from-german-embassy) However it may make sense to wait to reapply until your circumstances change.