# Visiting cousin in Belgium(who have Belgium passport)

Tags: visas, belgium

I am Bangladeshi and visiting Belgium to meet my cousin. 
I received below documents from him 
 Annexe 3 bis (Formal letter of obligation) attested by city hall along with his other relevant documents. 
I will travel for 10 days 
From my side I gave my employer NOC , medical insurance and 
Flight reservations.i also submitted my 3 month bank statement. 
My question how my sponsorship will support me to get the visa. 
Thanks

Comment: Do you mean your cousin is financially sponsoring you? Or are they just inviting you, and you will pay for the trip from your own money?

Comment: Have you already submitted the application and provided biometrics? Are you asking for an opinion on whether the documents you’ve provided are sufficient, or on your chances of success in obtaining the visa?

Comment: Already submitted with bio metric.  Just want know my chances to get the visa with the mentioned documents. My cousin taking care all the expenses during my stay. I am only buying my plain ticket. He sent me formal letter of obligation Annexe 3

Answer (score 2):

No one can predict the outcome. If you’re eligible to apply, have completed the application correctly and truthfully, and have good quality supporting documents, all you can do is wait for the verdict. There’s a great graphic here [Schengen visa refused from German embassy](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/49478/schengen-visa-refused-from-german-embassy) that shows how the decision process works in general.