# Please help me prove my intention to return?

Tags: visas, schengen, applications, nigerian-citizens, latvia

So heres the story guys, i want to apply for a visit visa from nigeria to latvia to visit my gf to celebrate our one yr anniversary. We have been dating on facebook for a year now and Shes inviting me to visit her in latvia and shes covering all the cost of travelling amd living expenses. I am currently unemployed because i am a student. I still live with my parents and my dad has pledged supoort to my trip and living expenses too. Everything is in place. The finance, accomodation, transport and itinerary. I have only one problem, which is my proof to return.

As a student, i graduated in from law 2016, i just finished my nysc this year in april 2018 and while i am waiting to apply for law school, i have enrolled myself in a computer programme for 6 months to learn data base management in order to improve my academic portfolio. And now in between studying this course and waiting for law school in november, i am applying for a visit visa. Everybody apart from my family is saying hey ur reason might not be so bad. Just do it. While majority is making me feel horrible. I miss my gf and i want to see her badly. Please how can i prove my intention to return. I cannot get a job so fastly or buy a property or rent a house which i will not move into? What should i do? I have to submit my application for schengen visit visa to latvia on monday and i have no idea what to expect. Infact i have lost hope. Please tell me what to do

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you studying abroad? Are you returning in order to study? Are law and computer school in different countries? Which countries are these?

Comment: Please elaborate your question. Are you trying to prove your ties to back home for a foreign via application and wonder if these documents are enough? Or are you abroad and wish to come back?

Comment: The reasons to return you describe don’t seem particularly compelling to me - computer studies can be done online from anywhere, and an enrolment at law school that’s not confirmed/started doesn’t convince either.

Comment: Being a young person from Nigeria, you're already put in a basket and it's not a very good basket. Your chances are slim however they are what they are. Go ahead and apply, you never know.

Comment: @Traveller in nigeria i cannot learn computer studies online like in the developed places. It must be in person. And an enrollment  to law school cannot be confirmed until i get a slot which im very sure of getting.Because i will use a judges recommendation to get admission. Should i kill myself befoee these visa officers belive i just love my gf and want to meet her for the first time to celebrate our one year anniversary?I cant buy a house. I dont have the money. I cant buy a car or make a huge investment all i can show is my future plans in my home country after my return with original docs

Answer (score 2):

This excellent answer [Schengen visa refused from German embassy](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/49478/schengen-visa-refused-from-german-embassy) shows how risk factors relating to visa applicants are typically considered. Using this as a guide, your reasons to return don’t indicate that your chances of success are high.

Comment: So please advice me, what do i do? Do i hurry and buy a car or what? Please i need your advice. Thank you. As a young student whos graduated, what can i use to show intention of returning?

Comment: @Gideon, the best option is a stable, well-paid job. The second best option for a student may be acceptance at a prestigious university, so that the visa official would understand that you want to return there instead of staying in Latvia. (As I understand your posting, you're between different parts of your professional education.)

Comment: Yes i am but can i not take this waiting period to visit my girlfriend in latvia? I mean isnt that logical?

Comment: @Gideon, they are afraid that you want to become an illegal immigrant. (1) You have a girlfriend in Latvia. (2) You have been dating via facebook, which is still not the usual way to have a relationship. It might be suspected as a sham. (3) You have currently no job in Nigeria. The best option is to have your girlfriend visit **you** in Nigeria, not the other way around. (I know a German who married a man from Togo. She went to Togo several times, and when it came to moving to Germany there was no question that the relationship was real.)