# I need to know what paperwork is required for 'socio-economic situation' for a long-stay visa

Tags: visas, schengen, paperwork, us-citizens, long-term

I'm really confused on what to do. I'm a u.s citizen and I'm staying with a friend in france who is paying for my whole stay there. So I'm not sure what documents I would need to provide for the proof of ''socio-economic situation' I'm unemployed, I'm using my savings for this trip with that being  said does that mean my visa might be denied? even though my friends paying for everything so I won't taking a job from anyone.

Comment: How long are you intending to stay in France?

Comment: A visa can always be denied. An unemployed person looking to stay with a friend who is supposedly paying for everything is a high-risk profile for overstay and illegal working (not saying this is your plan, just in general).

Comment: @Aurora Although your question relates to France, the image in this question   https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/49478/schengen-visa-refused-from-german-embassy shows how the risk assessment of your application is likely to be made.

Comment: @Traveller I only plan to stay about six months. And I do have the funds to support myself if absolutely necessary. I just don't know what paperwork I need to have.

Comment: @Aurora You need to provide documents that demonstrate your intention to leave France before the expiry of the requested visa. This could include evidence of income (pension, investment etc), assets (eg property, savings), marriage certificate, family ties, university/college enrolment.

Comment: You plan to stay for six months in France, and you are unemployed? Are you aware Schengen visas allow you to stay for a [maximum of 90 days in a six month period](https://eeas.europa.eu/sites/eeas/files/frequently_asked_questions_en.pdf)? You definitely are looking to get denied the visa.

Comment: Please clarify what kind of a visa you're applying for.