# Schengen Visa Application - Travel insurance

Tags: visas, schengen, insurance, schengen-visas

I am planning to go to germany for 5 days, but my insurance policy is good for 15 days, will it be a problem on my visa application? The first application was refused so i decided to shorten the length of my stay.

Comment: If your first application was refused, then shortening your stay is not likely to change the outcome at all. There was some reason they decided to not let you enter the country. Shortening your stay is still entering the country.

Comment: They told me insufficient fund and the informations i have provided are unreliable, which leads to strong doubts of my true intention. I have already added funds on my account and decided just to shorten the days, and noted it on my cover letter.

Comment: If the visa officers consider the information in your original application to be unreliable, conjuring up a significant amount of money you didn't previously declare won't help. You need to address the original reliability issue, and explain satisfactorily where the extra money has come from. FWIW your travel insurance isn't likely to have any impact.

Comment: Thank you very much Greg & Cannon for these advises. I hope this time it will have a positive feedback.

Comment: @kath See https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/53411/schengen-visa-refusal-justification-for-the-purpose-and-conditions-of-the-inten and https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/49478/schengen-visa-refused-from-german-embassy

Answer (score 1):

The insurance requirement is a minimum.
You can be insured for longer and for more coverage, without the officials even taking note.

As you have shortened your travel plans, having a longer coverage is easy to explain.

Many people travel to several countries within a single travel and they usually have insurance for the whole travel, so longer than their time in any one country.