# Getting mom sponsored through her brother for Schengen

Tags: visas, schengen, germany, schengen-visas

I am in Germany with a 1 year contract which is ending in March. I have been promised an extension but it may take a couple of more months. But I thought of bringing my mom to Germany on schengen visa through her brother who is also here. Because I will be going to Sri Lanka this December and I can bring her with me when I come back. This will not be possible if I wait for my extension and then get a longer visa and then sponsor her as I only have 5 weeks to go before I leave for Sri Lanka on vacation.

So if he sponsors her, while I'm here, will that be problematic for her in getting the visa? I'm super confused, any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Why does she need a sponsor?  Is she unable to pay for the trip herself?

Comment: Yes, she is widowed and totally dependent on me.

Comment: @mayooran What ties to Sri Lanka will your mother be able to demonstrate? https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/49478/schengen-visa-refused-from-german-embassy

Comment: She has a house written to her name and what I have now is just a 1 year visa. Can we say that she will go back because of these?

Answer (score 2):

Usually applicants for a Schengen visa have to **document the source of their funds**, which is not quite the same as having a sponsor. They also have to demonstrate why they would leave again.

In Germany, there is the *option* of formal sponsorship for a visitor visa in the form of a [Verpflichtungserklärung](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verpflichtungserkl%C3%A4rung_(Ausl%C3%A4nderrecht)), a document where the sponsor guarantees to reimburse the German state for any costs should there be an overstay. Most visitors get their visa without a Verpflichtungserklärung, but it can make the difference in cases which would otherwise be denied. To make such a formal declaration, one has to be a resident and earn enough to cover likely costs.

And there might be the possibility of declaring your mother your dependent. That's difficult, and Expatriates Stack Exchange is a better place to ask.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! When you meant "possibility of declaring your mother your dependent" you mean its possible to bring her for a long term stay?

Comment: @mayooran, that depends on the circumstances. Usually it is not possible, but sometimes it is. There would have to be an *unusual* hardship, you would have to be able to pay for her livelihood long-term, and even then the immigration office "can" rather than "should" approve it. Lots of hurdles, but it isn't impossible. Ask on Expatriates Stack Exchange, probably ask a qualified lawyer.

Comment: @mayooran, you should read up on both options before you do anything. There are not many of these family reunifications for parents, and you would have to explain why she **cannot stay** in Sri Lanka. For a visitor visa, you would have to explain why she **would return** to Sri Lanka. In is a bad idea to lie in an application, but people always try to present their facts in the best light. There should be no discrepancies if both applications are compared.

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing the thoughts with me. The real reason is that, currently she is staying with my wife there. So she can go back. Once I bring my wife here on a permanent basis, she will not have anyone to look after. She is also dependent on me monetary wise. So I will have to bring her here and I can pay for all the livelihood expenses here in Germany. Do you think that'd help?

Comment: @mayooran, it will *help* but I cannot really say if it will be *enough*. If you think about that, talk to an immigration lawyer. Maybe ask first on Expatriates Stack Exchange,