# Schengen Visa: Can I use a recently owned property as a proof of strong ties to host country?

Tags: indian-citizens, germany, schengen-visas

**Update: I got my visa.**

I am 24 years old and I am from India.

Last year, I planned to visit Graspop Metal in Belgium, and my visa got rejected with an explanation that

> Your intention to leave the territory of the Member States before the expiry of the visa applied for could not be ascertained.

I do accept, my application was too weak. I didn't prepare well.

This year, I am planning to attend Rock m' Ring in Germany. I have decided to spend a total of 18 days(1 June - 18 June). During my stay in Germany, I plan to visit Frankfurt, Black Forest, Berlin, and Munich. It doesn't include the 4 days for which I'd be at Rock m' Ring.

I'll be applying in April and this what the situation is. By the time I would apply, i'd have;

- Around 5000 euros in my savings account
- Around 3000 euros in investments. These investments come with a lock-in period of 5 years.
- A monthly income of 1115 euros.
- Rock m' Ring Festival ticket, and a camping ticket as well.
- Round trip confirmed flight tickets, Mumbai - Frankfurt.
- Booked accommodation in places that I'd visit.

Apart from that, I currently work for a US-based company as a contractor. I don't have a criminal background of any sort.

However, the issue that seems to cause the trouble is, I don't have any liabilities in India. I am not married, I don't own any property, nor is anyone dependant on me. And as I have searched around on the internet, that seems to be the number one cause of visa rejection.

Although, my mother owns a piece of land and I might be able to get it registered under my name. I told my parents that I need it for the visa purposes and they agreed. However, would it be found suspicious that I'd have a piece of land registered under my name just a month before application? For example, when people spike up their bank balance by transferring huge amounts of money to their bank account, and that is considered a malicious practice.

What can be done about it?

Thank you.

Comment: IMHO anything that significantly improves an applicant’s circumstances in the immediate run up to a visa application could be a red flag. Another potential problem is your employment - does your contract work tie you to India or is it remote working that could be done from anywhere?

Comment: @relentless-coder I think you correctly identify the issue here: a recent transfer from a relative with no showing that you actually paid for the property looks *exactly* like funds-parking, except with property instead of money. A perception of funds-parking will immediately yield a denial of the application. Were I the examiner here, I would certainly conclude you're trying to puff up your application in the same manner, and deny.

Comment: @Traveller The situation is that we are a team of 15 people that work from a wework office. The only reason that it's a contract is since that company isn't yet registered in India. I visit my parents back home quarterly for a week, and the company does let me work remotely, but in the end I have to return to the office.

Comment: @David what are my options then? Can my investments help me with this?

Comment: Can you get your employer to provide any backing for you being required to work in their office regularly?

Comment: @mdewey Would it really matter if the company isn't registered in India? I can ask my employer to include the clause in my contract letter, but I doubt if the visa officials would consider it.

Comment: Do you have a travel history? Proof of visiting (and leaving within the correct limits) of foreign countries whose visa requirements for Indian citizens are more lax than the EU's. If nothing else it helps show that you have been a genuine traveler in the past.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas yes, I've been to Singapore and Malaysia for a week. Although, I traveled with my family.

Comment: @relentless-coder It shouldn’t matter that the company isn’t registered in India IMHO. What might matter is that if you can do your job remotely it’s not as strong a reason to return home. You might find it helpful to read this https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/49478/schengen-visa-refused-from-german-embassy if you haven’t already done so

Comment: @Traveller no I can't do my job remotely, I work in the engineering department, rest of the engineers work from the same office. Are there any other options to provide intent of return?

Comment: @Traveller ah, thanks. Kind of that's what I wanted to hear right now, I was freaking out over it. Whatever might be the result, I can at least prepare a good application.

Comment: Your profile looks good. Avoid the land thing. Give it your best shot.

Comment: @relentless-coder Is there a way to pm you somehow? I had this same issue and my spain visa interview is on 17th. Is there a way for me to pm you ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Anything that significantly improves an applicant’s circumstances in the immediate run up to a visa application is likely to be a red flag unless it can be fully and credibly explained. A recent property transfer from a relative without proof that you actually paid anything for it looks exactly like funds-parking, except with property instead of money. That is likely to be a quick route to another refusal.

You are right in saying that lack of ties is a major factor in many refusals, and right to be concerned about this given your previous refusal. However, looking at the positives: you have a job and savings (for which you have supporting evidence in the form of payslips, contract, and bank statements) sufficient to meet the €45 per day minimum; a travel history (limited, but probably in line with expectations for an applicant in your situation); and a credible premise/itinerary for the trip which isn’t going to cost an unrealistic multiplier of your monthly income.

On balance, despite your previous refusal, with a carefully prepared application it looks hopeful this time. I don’t think there’s any more you can do.

Answer (score 3):

I agree property suddenly appearing on your asset sheet would appear as a ruse; especially once they find out it's bare land, and *double especially* if it appears to be difficult to develop by Indian standards, e.g. Lack of viable public transport to it in a place few own cars. The equivalent in the US would be  roadless timberland, or a landlocked parcel with no easements onto the property.

One of my favorite examples is someone who is a classic drifter and has no community ties. Except she is wearing a Taylor Swift T-shirt and has a long string of passport stamps that conform *exactly* to Taylor Swift's world tour schedule *exactly*, with a fortune in onward travel already booked to future tour  stops. And a phone with photos from over 200 concerts.  Yeah, immigration can be sure she won't overstay.

For you, a history of going to metal (?) shows and then leaving as agreed, will help.

A big strike against you is the highly mobile, gypsy-like  nature of telecommuting employment, in the absence of any other ties to India.  And I know (from comments) that your job isn't *that* telecommutable, but **immigration doesn't know that**! Your skill does telecommute well, which makes it easy to get work beyond the reach of EU employment law.  So it's really hard to be sure you won't take up residence in a local coffee shop and never leave.

One thing that helps is, don't bring your tools-of-trade, e.g. Your laptop.  Arrive wholly unprepared to work. That can be a bit scary, I know!

Comment: No, this is the first time, if I get the visa, I'd be attending a concert outside India. I applied for the Belgium visa last year, but it got rejected. I have a question, France visa for Indian tourists turns out to be most lax, is it okay if I apply for a French visa, and then travel to Germany from France?

Comment: That's another question, and I think it has a detailed answer on this stack.

Comment: @relentless-coder No - Schengen Visa rules require you to apply to the country that is your main destination. Trying to ‘visa shop’ will get you a rejected application or worse - don’t try to game the system if you want to be successful. https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13362/should-my-first-trip-be-to-the-country-which-issued-my-schengen-visa

Comment: @relentless-coder More generally, your best chance is to present a simple, clear, coherent application. What is really going on, a trip to Germany centered on a concert with sightseeing, on vacation from a job, makes sense. Adding complications such as property transfers and visa shopping breaks that nice, simple story.