# 3 time Schengen visa denial- having Sweden Personnumer

Tags: visas, schengen-visas, sweden, denial-of-entry

I have been rejected from Schengen Area 3 time in last 1.5 year( first from spain and the next 2 times from France) ,All with the reason they were not satisfied me to leave Schengen area.
In 2013 I have admitted in one of Swedish universities and then got Swedish 13 month resident card.But after 3 month I had to come back from Sweden to my home country.

My question:
Does having Swedish identity number from that time helps me to apply for tourist visa in Sweden and take the visa?
I have been rejected 3 time which really is unfair . My dics always were complete.
I got deppressed of this situation snt want to apply from Sweden.
PS: I just want to go there to see some of my friends. Thats it.

Comment: I don't quite understand the reasoning in the question. I would have thought that a prior residence card suggests a tendency to live in Europe, rather than the opposite.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan The OP went to Sweden as a student but left the university after just three months. This is viewed very negatively.

Comment: Related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/49478/schengen-visa-refused-from-german-embassy

Comment: @MichaelHampton  - thanks for replies. Actually I already had informed my university at that time that because of my mom's disease I must leave university (it was really hard for me as I have been awarded full fund scholarship) - @ PatriciaShanahan -- My question is my previous Social Sequrity number from Sweden (Personnumer) will help me in taking visa from there or not? 3 time visa denial has made me confused.

Comment: You’re not going to get a visitor visa to Sweden anytime soon after three successive close refusals from other Schengen countries. Forget it! They don’t care about your depression, and your Swedish identity number is meaningless. Tell your friends to visit you.