# Does travelling solo without previous travel history affect Schengen Visa application?

Tags: schengen, schengen-visas, solo-travel

I was told by a Visa agent that, if I am going solo and don't have a travel history, it is hard for the people at the consulate to believe I am going for legal trip. And this is because, apparently, not many people from India travel solo.

How true is this?

Comment: The visa agent is giving you a simplistic view - travelling solo probably isn’t the reason in itself but would combine with other factors relating to the applicant’s circumstance to produce a refusal. The graphic in this question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/49478/schengen-visa-refused-from-german-embassy explains how the risk assessment process generally works

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no rule against traveling solo.

There is no rule against traveling for the first time.

If you use a visa agent then you should make *really* sure that you understand what you sign and that it is the truth. Honest visa agents help their clients with confusing application forms, for a fee. Dishonest visa agents enter lies for their clients, but it is the client who suffers if the lie is found out.

Regarding your application, ask yourself if you can *reasonably* afford the trip, and if someone who doesn't know you has *reason to believe* that you are no illegal immigrant.

- Who pays the trip and why? In the best case, you can afford the trip from your own income and the cost is just a small part of your annual income. For young people, it could be relatives who pay. Then the questions are:

  - Why is the money given?
  - Is it really a gift or is it a credit?
  - Was the money earned legally? Can the giver afford the gift?
- Do you have a stable job or a stable course of education? It would be best if you earn more in India than an illegal worker or asylum applicant would get in Europe. But they understand that this isn't always the case for young people.