# How significant is previous Schengen travel to improve the likelihood of an approval?

Tags: schengen-visas

For a Schengen visa, how much does previous history of travel within the Schengen matter in terms of improving the likelihood of being approved?

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Previous Schengen travel history probably helps, but we can't say with authority that it does or to what extent, much less prove it. The officer reviewing your application is going to look at the merits of the overall application and the overall risk in granting you a visa, and previous travel history may or may not be significant for either, or may not be significant enough. [Gayot Fow's answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/49498/1480) to a different question may be useful to read.

Comment: All other things being equal, it will help a lot. You were there, you didn't overstay, that makes it seem less likely that you will overstay now. But things might have changed, either in your personal situation (job, family, ...) or in the data the EU has about you.