# Is it mandatory to have travel History before Applying for Tourist visa to Canada

Tags: visas, canada, history

As the above subject states, how mandatory is it to have travel history before applying to Canada? If i work in an office (Full time),  have small business (part time (which is registered with the government here in this country, Nigeria)) , dependent parents, BUT I do not have a travel History. Is this a barrier of some sort.

Comment: It's not required but helps with your application, it also helps when you present them your round trip tickets. Having dependents/job in your country of origin helps. If you are single and have no travel history in combination will not help because they think you might come to marry someone. All you could do is present the strongest case possible and hope for the best.

Comment: Another question you wrote today says that you do have a travel history! it says that you have travelled to Ghana and South Africa. This is not an extensive travel history, certainly, but it is a travel history.

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't find a valid source for this, but according to this (poorly written) [Quora answer](https://www.quora.com/Can-I-get-a-Canadian-tourist-visa-with-no-travel-history-and-any-invitation) and from my own understanding of the process, it is *not* mandatory to have any travel history. Of course, having a past travel history in countries such as the US or UK might help your application.

What *is* important is making sure you don't hide any past travel history, as that will definitely put up a red flag.

As for the other things you mentioned, having a full-time job, a business and family in your home country are all things that would look good on your application. The biggest worry they have is you overstaying your visa and becoming an illegal immigrant. Also, since this is a tourist visa, sharing your tickets (for both ways) is also something you could add to your application.

All this being said, you'd be better off asking people who have first-hand experience with Canadian Tourist Visa's for Nigerians, either through a travel agent or an internet forum.

All the best!

Answer (score 1):

A range of factors, of which travel history is one, is taken into account when visa applications are assessed. This answer relates to a Schengen application [Schengen visa refused from German embassy](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/49478/schengen-visa-refused-from-german-embassy) but the principle is similar for any destination and is demonstrated in the graphic included in the answer.

In your case, a lack of travel history coupled with a high country risk rating could be a red flag, but if your application is strong in other risk factor areas you may ‘score’ enough to overcome the red flag.