# Schengen visa application was refused twice. Will this affect my UK visa application?

Tags: uk, schengen-visas, standard-visitor-visas

My schengen visa got refused twice.

First time was in 2018 when I had an invitation letter from a university in Barcelona to attend a summer camp.Visa got refused for the very common 2 vague reasons “the information provided regarding conditions of stay and accommodation are not reliable” and “conditions and purpose of stay are not justified” though the invitation letter clearly stated that accommodation is provided inside the university. Note: the visa type was “business”.

Second time was in 2019, I applied with a group of my friends for a tourism visa to visit france. We all had the exact same documents and attended the same group appointment to submit documents and biometrics. I was the only one who got refused for the reason “The information submitted regarding the justification for the purpose and conditions of the intended stay was not reliable”.

I am quite certain that this is non sense because our documents including bookings, flights and itinerary are identical however, I am the only one who has never travelled anywhere before. This might be the unmentioned true reason for refusal in my perspective.

Now I plan to travel to the UK to visit my cousins for 10 days, I have all the documents prepared precisely, justified every little detail in my application, I attached everything that proves I have ties within my country (I’m a college student) and I have an invitation letter fully supporting my stay during the travelling period in the UK. Also, I submitted bank statements in my support, one of them is mine and it has some random deposits which I think won’t be a problem since I am an unemployed student and don’t have a salary.

The question is should I go for it? Because I am really afraid and I can’t take another visa refusal which can potentially affect my future visas.

Please give me advice considering that I can still cancel the visa application before it gets processed and postpone the visit to a later time.  Also note that the travel dates are soon and I am not sure it would take less than 15 working days to process the application.

Comment: Have you travelled anywhere else in the interim? Are you paying for the proposed UK trip yourself? Lack of a travel history and needing a sponsor are likely to be seen as red flags (see the graphic in this question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/49478/schengen-visa-refused-from-german-embassy explaining how risk assessment typically works)

Comment: I have never travelled anywhere outside of the country, as I've mentioned in my answer. I also had a look at the graphic, but I still have no idea how to establish that I have social and economic ties to my country in light of the fact that I’m a college student without a job.

Comment: Unfortunately that can be pretty hard to do unless you have eg dependent family or provable responsibilities/role in your local community. The typical advice is to build up a travel history by visiting countries with less stringent requirements, and/or defer applying to those that do set the bar high until you have completed your studies and have a job, savings. Just an opinion, but the outcome of an application to the UK is likely to be the same as it was for your Schengen applications unless your personal circumstances have changed. Even with a sponsor inviting you, you still have to qualify

Comment: You should carefully read [Schengen Visa Refusal: Justification for the purpose and conditions of the intended stay was not reliable](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/53411/3221). This explains why people get this refusal reason and how to overcome it. In your case I would keep in mind that visa officers do not like "some random deposits" into bank accounts without explanation. This is also true of the UK. Unexplained bank account deposits are a very frequent cause of visa refusal, both for Schengen and for UK.