# Visa Refusal and Re apply third time

Tags: schengen, visa-refusals, spain, poland

One year ago i have applied for tourist and student visa to Spain and got refused. Now i got a chance to visit Poland. Can i re-apply for a tourist visa? Will it get refused because of my previous rejection?

Comment: In theory, not "because of it", but they will know about the refusal, and if the reasons for refusal still stand, they will apply the same reasoning. Unless you address the issues they led to the previous refusal, you should probably expect the same result.

Comment: What were the reasons for the two refusals from Spain? Have your personal circumstances changed since you last applied (that is, have they improved sufficiently so that you could demonstrate in a new application that the previous refusal reasons no longer apply to you)?

Comment: Thank you for the response. 1st time (August 2017) i applied spain tourist with my whole family and it got refused due to 2 reason ( intention to leave the country  not ascertained and information submitted to stay was not reliable), in 2018 i got a chance to study spanish course in a university and i have applied a student visa with all sufficient documents but it again got refused due to that same 2 reasons. so i stopped applying and it almost one year. Now i got a chance to visit poland from (sponsor) my friend and im scared to apply again. please advise me

Comment: Thank you for your comments. The person who sponsoring me is a poland citizen and if i provide a lawyer letter from poland confirming that i ll return to my home country, will it be helpful for my tourist visa?

Comment: @Berny The answer to this question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/49478/schengen-visa-refused-from-german-embassy contains a great graphic that explains how a visa application is typically risk-assessed. Take a look at the factors it shows, it might help you decide if your personal circumstances have changed sufficiently since your previous refusal to make it worthwhile filing another application. A lawyer’s letter confirming you’ll return to your home country is utterly useless.

Answer (score 2):

A previous visa rejection does not in itself disqualify you from obtaining a visa later, but information from an earlier visa application, successful or not, may be used against you.

For a more specific answer, please provide more information, especially about the reason for the rejection.

---

Based on your comment with additional information:

The main issue seems to be your situation in your home country. The authorities want to be convinced that you have something to which you want to return. If you have a well-paid job, run a successful business or own a nice house you may seem more likely to go back home rather than trying to leave your old life behind and remain in the Schengen States. Other factors like nationality, age, education and family situation may also be taken into account, when assessing the risk of you overstaying.

It does seem that the authorities also found your travel arrangements improbable in some way. This did not help you, but might not have been an issue if otherwise would have seemed very likely to return home in time.

The good news: Your previous rejected applications will likely not prevent you from getting a visa if you can address the reasons.

The bad news: It may be very difficult for you to convince the authorities that you have strong reasons to go back home. They want to see strong ties to your home country, which may not be easy to create. Have your economy improved since last time? Have you got a new job? Is your family situation different?

Comment: Thank you for the response. 1st time (August 2017) i applied spain tourist with my whole family and it got refused due to 2 reason ( intention to leave the country  not ascertained and information submitted to stay was not reliable), in 2018 i got a chance to study spanish course in a university and i have applied a student visa with all sufficient documents but it again got refused due to that same 2 reasons. so i stopped applying and it almost one year. Now i got a chance to visit poland from (sponsor) my friend and im scared to apply again. please advise me.