# How duration of Schengen Visa Validity is decided

Tags: schengen-visas, france, uk-residents, embassies

I would like to know what are the factors an embassy (from any Schengen country, in my case France) takes into consideration while granting the duration of Schengen Visa.

- I have applied for Schengen Visa (multiple entry) for the first time (with the French Embassy) last year and I got just for 6 months while all my friends who applied along with me for the first time got for a year.
- I again applied for the same Schengen Visa (multiple entry) for the second time this year and I got only for 4 months while my other friend who applied along with me has got for a year.

I'm confused why it happens.

When I was applying second time (with French Embassy) , I did write acover letter mentioning that I have trip plans to France till the end of next summer and I had requested for longer duration of Schengen Visa but in turn I got lesser period of stay than last time. It's disappointing.

I'm trying to understand why it happens? because I'm intending to apply one more Schengen visa for next year summer.

Is it possible that I can appeal with French embassy to extend my duration of Schengen Visa?

Can anyone suggest me a country for which I could get a longer duration of Schengen Visa next time?

PS: I'm happy with duration of stay which is 90 days But my question is more about duration of Visa Validity.

Comment: Is your UK visa expiring soon?

Comment: Did you friend explicitly ask for a multiple-entry visa?

Comment: Are your friends’ circumstances 100% the same as yours? Citizenship, travel history, current occupation, financial standing, ties to home/country of residence, premise for the visa application etc etc? The graphic in this answer https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/49478/schengen-visa-refused-from-german-embassy might be helpful

Comment: @MichaelHampton - Yes 4 months and My friends visa also expires in 4 months

Comment: @Relaxed - Both of us asked for multiple entry visa

Comment: @Traveller - My friend has got his first schengen visa for france some 8 years ago whereas I got my schengen visa last year other than that I am more qualified than him for example I got more balance in my financial statement.

Comment: It sounds like your friend has more travel history in Schengen than you do. That may be a factor in why he received a longer visa.

Comment: Yeah that's possible. Next time I would like to apply & get longer term of visa. Should I try france again or any other country ?

Answer (score 2):

I have heard countless examples of people getting multiple entry visas in other situations or even without asking for one but in principle they are intended for regular professional or family visits, not as a convenience for tourists (cf. article 24 of the Schengen visa code). It's also intended for travellers who have proved their reliability and this is only your second application. So the decision appears to be correct and there is not much you can do to force their hand. Even if it wasn't, appealing is hopeless and not an option for something like that.

Comment: This doesn't go very far to answering the question about the factors taken into account when determining the length of the visa's period of validity.

Comment: @phoog No indeed, I didn't take the time to acknowledge that but the OP actually asked several question, including one on whether an appeal is in order, which I felt deserved a quick answer.

Comment: @Relaxed  - Next time I would like to apply & get longer term of visa. Which country should I apply for ? Same france