# African Nations travel History not valid for Canada TRV?

Tags: visas, canada, paperwork, nigerian-citizens

How true is this? Is it true that Travel history for African Nations are not valid when Applying for Canada TRV? I have over 6 entry stamps for mainly African Nations, Rwanda, South Africa and Mauritius included. I am from Nigeria. Is it true that travel history from African Nations are not in anyway recognized?

Comment: @Traveller thanks for the Response. Rwanda and South Africa places visa stamps inside passports. That said, We have to apply and then get the stamps inside the passport prior to arrival. Nothing like visa upon arrival for us at this point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It’s not so much that a travel history to African nations is not recognised, it’s more that it probably won’t be given the same weight as a travel history that includes countries with equivalent standing to Canada eg USA, Schengen zone, UK, Australia.

Travel history is only one risk factor typically  considered by Immigration officials when assessing a visa application. The graphic in this question [Schengen visa refused from German embassy](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/49478/schengen-visa-refused-from-german-embassy) shows how a visa application might be risk-assessed in general, irrespective of the country to which you’re applying.

Comment: Ah nice. So can Turkey be rated as one of those nations with that standard? Kindly let me know

Comment: @Hashim Although such information isn’t publicly disclosed, the likelihood is ‘no’, if only because Turkey isn’t part of the Schengen zone. Nigeria is generally viewed as high risk, as you’ll probably know.

Comment: hungary is part of the schengen zone, I think I should submit there then

Comment: @Hashim The refusal rate for applications to Hungary from Nigeria was c52% according to https://statistics.schengenvisainfo.com/

Comment: @Traveller: _Why_ isn't this information publicly disclosed?

Comment: @Sean It is https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/visa-policy_en

Comment: @Sean If you mean "why don't countries provide a detailed 'mark scheme' for visitor visa applications (like some do for long term visas)", then there would be a tendency for the actual bad actors to optimise their visitor applications towards countries they wish to move to permanently.