# Schengen Visa: Young, unmarried, and self-employed—how do I get a tourist visa with such a profile?

Tags: indian-citizens, schengen-visas, norway

Edit: I just want to add that I don't have any employment with a particular company and that has made my situation difficult. I've asked this question as I couldn't find anything specific for self-employed and unmarried. I checked other threads and I followed everything to the T— sufficient bank balance, IT returns, detailed itinerary, bookings, everything. I want to understand what more can I do apart from the usual things (which I did last time).

My tourist visa was recently refused on the grounds of weak ties to home country. I'm 23 years old, female, unmarried, and have a sole proprietorship. I do have business registration papers and I also have hired 2 employees under me. But we work remotely. I have other financial documents like income tax return as well.

But as you see, my profile is a straight no in the eyes of visa officer.

I'm thinking of making my situation better by the end of this year and apply again.

More info: I rent an apartment and don't live with parents. I'm also the guardian of my sister but I don't have any legal papers to show for it. My sister (who's 18) is completely dependent on me but how do I prove this?

I'm also expecting a huge increase in my income by the end of this year so can that help? I honestly have no idea how much money would be enough.

My purpose is strictly tourism and I have zero intention of staying back. I'm just lost as to how do I *prove* it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Schengen Visa Application: what are some helpful tips for preparing?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51048/schengen-visa-application-what-are-some-helpful-tips-for-preparing)

Comment: How long has your business been operating? How profitable is it? Where is the ‘huge increase in income’ coming from and is it permanent? **What prior travel history do you have?** (It’s highly unlikely you’ll get a Schengen visa without one). Is your sister dependent on you financially? If so, you should provide evidence of the funds you give her. If she’s dependent on you for eg personal care, provide medical evidence and/or proof of who would care for her while you’re away. Based on your questions *‘Making your situation better by the end of the year’* just doesn’t seem credible or possible

Comment: @Traveller - I checked almost every thread and to my surprise, I actually followed everything when I applied the last time. I've been operating since 1.5 years but I was working solo. I hired first employee 6 months ago. I have visited Dubai once. My sister is completely dependent on me, from college fee to other things. How do I provide the evidence of the funds I give to her? For eg, she was hospitalized recently and I covered the entire hospital fee. But how do I prove **I** paid it? Thanks so much!

Comment: The same way you prove anything financial - by paperwork eg bank statements, hospital invoice. And sorry, but with your profile one trip to Dubai isn’t going to be enough to convince an IO you’ll return to your home country. Forget about Schengen for now, build a decent travel history before reapplying. Remember that every refusal will likely make it even harder to get a visa, from Schengen or indeed other comparable destinations

Comment: @Traveller Would you suggest building my travel history more? When I submitted my documents, the person at the VFS didn't accept my Dubai stamps and said **only Schengen or other countries are considered**

Comment: @Traveller -- thanks again. One more question, it's fine if I can get it next year too. I just want to understand all the things I can do to get the visa someday and travel. What are the things or documents I can do/collect from now on to make my chances better? I've also edited question to be clearer

Comment: This is not Business Advise SE, but if you have employees, you *really* need to look into incorporating as a "real" company, or you risk losing everything you own if something goes wrong.  And it'll help with the visa application too.

Comment: If your business is incorporated, then you are employed by the corporation and not self-employed. It's not much compared to be being employed by a large corp but it indicates connections to the homeland since you likely paid lawyers and accountants handsomely and on an ongoing basis.

Comment: In India, it means incorporating as a Private Limited company. It makes your life easier, not only for visa.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My Schengen visa (Norway) was rejected even after I did everything right. What could be the reason?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/176877/my-schengen-visa-norway-was-rejected-even-after-i-did-everything-right-what-c)

Answer (score 6):

Forget about Schengen for a few years. A rapid second application will just get you a second refusal.

In a comment you mentioned that your travel history consists of one visit to Dubai. *You are very unlikely* to get a Schengen visa (or a US visa, or the UK, or any other comparable destination) without being able to show a much better record of having travelled outside of and returned to your country.

In the meantime, keep paperwork for every major aspect of your life, including regular financial support for your sister and invoices/receipts for ad hoc expenses. You might also consider incorporating your sole proprietorship into a Private Limited company, as has been suggested in several comments.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer and all the help. Thank you so much. It was just the dream of seeing the Northern lights that kind of made it rushed in my mind. But I understand and would explore other places + keep documents of everything. Thanks again!

Comment: Asked by @Traveler and answered by Traveller :) . At 23 you are still very young so you have a lot of time. You could travel to places that have easier visa policies like South East Asia, Hong Kong etc. Even Japan visa is relatively easier to get these days and it lets you into a few other countries visa-free.