# Applying Schengen Learnings

Tags: schengen, europe, denmark, visa-rejections, estonia

This should be treated as an advise rather a questions that I resolved myself.

My story is simple but answers are only rejection so far

1. Applied French visa 2019 after a friend inviting me who I have met in my country fully sponsored trip but documentation was vague like too many stops with no clear directions
2. Then after two years my sibling is now a resident who lives in Denmark I applied a visa to visit him the rejection came on the point number 13
3. I applied again next year same reason for rejection but with two letter legal response saying I am young and have not established a family in home country
4. I tried with documents certified and proving my stay and reasons for coming back again same justification with addition saying my business is newly established
5. I tried Estonia residency short term less than 30 days that is digital nomad visa they rejected on the reason for number 10

My profile is I am self employed 30 years with a gf from US, I have worked in tech as freelancer and remote job and built businesses in my home country so my documents are quite clean and authenticated in the case of Denmark my brother provided a company certified document saying that I hold family and business office on behalf of the business registers by him in my home country.

Now I am left with apply residency in EU or Forget about ever going to EU this raises doubt about further western visas that I might be applying

Should I do what ?

Updates

1. Learning #1 Never apply with vague answers , and incomplete documentation , double check your documents, in my case there were many.
2. Learning #2 Some countries does not recognise brother as close kin like Denmark does not recognise Brothers as close relationship and does not consider it as a family visit. Always research before banging your head against the wall.
3. Learning #3. I had an interview with the Danish Embassy , it went really bad they figured out that there was something fishy although there was nothing at all but I spoke about the business and relationship with my brother. So don't speak too much.
4. Learning #4 Your documents will never be enough so just be concise.
5. Learning #5 I think trying Business Visa is a better option if you can arrange one , we had multiple businesses in EU but never thought of trying with that.
6. Learning #6 Clearly state your intention and time for travel.
7. Learning #7 Pay attention to details , they are humans too and they can make mistakes.
8. Forget and Forgive.

In the end I entered EU after applying for a residency permit on Employment basis in small country known as Latvia.

Comment: What's your actual citizenship and what passport(s) do you hold ?

Comment: I have Indian citizenship

Comment: Partly , but I am still researching..

Comment: Best avoid applying for visa till your situation has really changed. Each rejection counts against you. The more you try the more deparate you seem.

Comment: You might also review [this question, comments, and answers](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/176877/my-schengen-visa-norway-was-rejected-even-after-i-did-everything-right-what-c/177193#177193)

Comment: @Willeke my situation change is happening every day, but this presents a threat for me to be able to freely move and network with people

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica India overstaying in EU is there and I believe that’s why such law in place now planning a residency

Comment: *Should I do what?* Stop making applications that make you appear desperate to get to the EU and are highly likely to increase the chance of a refusal from similarly sought-after jurisdictions. Build up a travel history. Acquire some tangible assets (eg property) that might be a tie to your home country. Related questions https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/52782/schengen-visa-refusal-justification-for-the-purpose-and-conditions-of-the-inten and https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/49478/schengen-visa-refused-from-german-embassy

Comment: Note that less than 30 days is not a residency application, it's a regular Schengen visa. Anything related to freelancing, remote work or being a digital nomad doesn't play in your favor. If you want to apply for EU residency, you might have better luck with formal employment from a company based in the EU (Blue card or the like if you can get it). Then your history becomes irrelevant because establishing residency is the (legitimate) purpose of the application. It's the risk or impression that you want to live in the EU without applying for a proper long-stay visa that's the problem.

Comment: On the other hand, if you just want to visit, you will need property, kids, an office job from an established company, things you cannot move easily under the radar to establish strong ties to India. Remote self-employment, even sincere and well documented doesn't help you with that.

Comment: @Traveller I am not making any application, for now, that is short term and Schengen.

Comment: @Relaxed I realised that is the case when Denmark rejected my application and sent me a note stating that I am trying to reside in EU and the response was more or less like if i am applying for residency permit.