# Is it worth appealing a France visa refusal?

Tags: indian-citizens, visa-refusals, schengen-visas, france, visa-refusal-appeal

My France visa was rejected 2 times. I had submitted all relevant documents with strong ties with my home country. I provided a detailed itinerary day by day and all confirmed bookings of flights and hotels.

Now I have cancelled my trip but I have appealed the decision.

So did anyone have any success with appeal without a French lawyer?

Reason of refusal both time was justification and purpose not reliable.

Brief Summary:

I have an Indian passport with no travel history and am single. I earn more than 2,500 Euros per month and attached assets of my stocks portfolio, which had close to 20k Euros. I attached NOC and ITR, bank statement, everything.

Comment: For completeness, what is your citizenship and what were the refusal reason(s)?

Comment: I am from India and the reason was justification and purpose not reliable.

Comment: I have gone through https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/53411/schengen-visa-refusal-justification-for-the-purpose-and-conditions-of-the-inten and dont find anything related to me

Comment: It might help you get an answer if you edit your question to include a brief summary of your personal circumstances (eg travel history, job/income, marital status, assets in India, purpose/duration of trip and itinerary), when you applied, and what improvements on your first application/paperwork you made for your second one to address the refusal reason. Which (if any) risk assessment element in [this graphic](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/49478/schengen-visa-refused-from-german-embassy-intention-to-leave-could-not-be-ascer) might be against you? What reason are you appealing on?

Comment: Details updated. Also in my 2nd attempt, i added detailed day wise itinerary which was missing earlier and also provided NOC from the employer. Appealing on basis that i added all confirmed booking. iternary provided. NOC and Bus tickets for intercity as well

Comment: **No travel history and single**. There you have it. Your chances of an appeal success are vanishingly small, IMHO.

Comment: I dont understand why do they think i will not come to back my country. I am earning more than France average salary. Also i wanted to travel europe for first time only. Dont know why asians are treated like this :(

Comment: @kk_sad I don't know your personal circumstances, but a wild guess just for illustration could be that you might be earning those 2500€ in a way which would be easily transferable to Europe (let's say you're an expert in IT or finance), so having such a job in India does not actually tie you much to India. Similarly, stock portfolios are quite easy to move to a different country, so they don't really mean much in terms of ties.

Comment: Haha, by that case if i have property in india. I can easily sell it and transfer to europe and if any family member lives here, i can also call them by applying visa :)

Comment: @kk_sad It’s pretty well-recognised that getting a tourist visa to sought-after destinations such as Schengen, Canada, USA, UK, Australia, typically requires the applicant to demonstrate a history of complying with immigration rules. Visiting a few countries where you can enter visa free or get a visa on arrival before trying again will increase your chances of success.

Comment: @Traveller thats just sad. I dont want to go to south east asia. I am forcefully sent to these countries just to get mentioned visas. Thats unfair but thats how life is

Comment: Thing is,two EU applications in a row with literally zero other travel history are quite a concerning signal for any visa officer. It shows a stubborn determination to get into the EU somehow and zero interest in the rest of the world. Genuine tourists rarely act like that, because there's a lot to be seen all over the globe,not just in Europe. Visa officers are rarely capable of mind-reading or equipped with crystal balls,so all they can do is guess at your true motives based on the signals you give them.

Comment: See https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/53411/schengen-visa-refusal-justification-for-the-purpose-and-conditions-of-the-inten Old but still helpful.